# How to drop insignificant zeros when converting a BigDecimal to a String in Java?

Tags: java, tostring, bigdecimal

`java.math.BigDecimal.toString()` can return something like "0.888200000". What can be the best I can do if I want "0.8882" instead? I can never know (unless I calculate it for every particular case) the length of the integer (left to the point) part, the value can be 123.8882 as easily as 123456.88.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `stripTrailingZeros()`:

> Returns a BigDecimal which is numerically equal to this one but with any trailing zeros removed from the representation.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: Thanks. I've missed it as I am actually coding Scala and its standard BigDecimal wrapper doesn't seem to have stripTrailingZeros :-(

Comment: @Ivan: The library is the same regardless of which language you use, surely? So hopefully it'll Just Work(tm).

Comment: Yes it is, @t-j-crowder, but we usually avoid using Java types directly unless necessary in Scala - we prefer to use Scala standard "wrapper" over the type (`scala.math.BigDecimal`) but it indeed encapsulates `java.math.BigDecimal` and we can access it to use a way the wrapper doesn't offer.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you fancy regular expressions:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*?)0*$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourString);
String result=m.group(1);
```

which might be faster than all the messy stuff the `BigInteger` class does internally in its `stripTrailingZeroes` method

Comment: A handy option to have. Thanks.